# View not reflecting state changes from service

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I've implemented email and password authentication using ViewModel and LiveData. My code looks like this:

**AuhtService.kt**

```
fun createNewUser(email: String, password: String): MutableLiveData<AuthData> {
    val authenticatedUserLiveData = MutableLiveData<AuthData>()

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("AuthService", "Created new user! $email")
                authenticatedUserLiveData.value = AuthData("success", task.result?.user, null)

                task.result?.user?.let {
                    DatabaseService.getDbInstance().collection("users")
                        .document(it.uid).set(it).addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Void> ->
                            Log.d("AuthService", "Added new user to database.")
                        }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(
                    "AuthService",
                    "Failed to create new user! $email ${task.exception?.message}"
                )
                authenticatedUserLiveData.value =
                    AuthData("failure", null, task.exception?.message)
            }
        }


    return authenticatedUserLiveData
}
```

This class performs the firebase operations and returns livedata of type `AuthData` which is basically a wrapper around `FirebaseUser` and a couple of strings to carry error messages in case Authentication fails.

**UserAuthViewModel.kt**

```
class UserAuthViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val authService = AuthService()

    enum class AuthState {
        AUTHENTICATED,
        UNAUTHENTICATED,
        INVALID_AUTH
    }

    val authState = MutableLiveData<AuthState>()
    val authErrorMsg = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var currentUser = MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser>()

    init {
        authErrorMsg.value = ""
        authState.value = AuthState.UNAUTHENTICATED
        currentUser = authService.getCurrentUser()
    }

    fun signInWithEmail(email: String, password: String) {
        val result = authService.loginWithEmail(email, password).value

        if (result?.status.equals("success")) {
            authState.value = AuthState.AUTHENTICATED
        } else {
            authState.value = AuthState.INVALID_AUTH
            authErrorMsg.value = result?.msg
        }

        currentUser.value = result?.data
    }

    fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {

        val result = authService.createNewUser(email, password).value

        if (result?.status.equals("success")) {
            authState.value = AuthState.AUTHENTICATED
        } else {
            authState.value = AuthState.INVALID_AUTH
            Log.d("AuthVM", result?.msg)
            authErrorMsg.value = result?.msg
        }

        currentUser.value = result?.data
    }
}
```

finally my **RegisterFragment.kt**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    userAuthViewModel.authState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { authState ->
        if (authState == UserAuthViewModel.AuthState.AUTHENTICATED) {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "User is ${userAuthViewModel.currentUser.value?.email}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        if(authState == UserAuthViewModel.AuthState.INVALID_AUTH) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "${userAuthViewModel.authErrorMsg.value}", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })

    register_button.setOnClickListener {
        val email = registerEmail_editText.editText?.text
        val pwd = registerPassword_editText.editText?.text

        userAuthViewModel.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.toString(), pwd.toString())
    }

    goToLoginButton.setOnClickListener{
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_registerFragment_to_loginFragment)
    }
}
```

The above code is mainly inspired from google docs and MVVM arch. but it behaves very weirdly, first of all I get a snackbar at the start with no text, secondly the error messages are not displayed in the sncakbar when auth fails. What am I doing wrong.

**Update:** On further testing it seems that `result?.msg` in my `UserAuthViewModel` is null, but I'm passing error messages in my AuthService, quite weird.

**Update 2:** Its seems in either case the else of `if (result?.status.equals("success"))` is being executed, am I doing string comparison wrong?

**Update 3:** I figured it out but I'm not sure what is the proper way to solve this. The *problem* is that although AuthServie returns a `MutableLiveData` that contains null values initially which will be replaced by proper values later (when async calls from AuthService finish). In the ViewModel I do this to propagate new AuthData when user perfroms a sign up

`val result = authService.createNewUser(email, password).value`

Problem is that doing this passes the initial LiveData object in the AuthService with null values to the ViewModel, so the View updates with null values, I need a way to so that the View can observe actual values when they get updated from authservice's callbacks.

Comment: check this code is executing or not  `authState.value = AuthState.AUTHENTICATED`.

Comment: Updated the question please check

Answer (score 0):

`createNewUser()` method is doing it's work asynchronously. Initially `authenticatedUserLiveData` is `null`. So you are getting `null` from viewmodel. You have to push a callback after `onCompleteListener()` called from `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. There are several ways to make this. Personally I use RxJava for async tasks. For better understanding you can make a interface will be called after success or error callback from firebase auth. Code will looks like this

callback interface can be:

```
interface AuthCallback {
    fun onUserCreationResult(authData: AuthData)
}
```

from `AuthService`

```
fun createNewUser(email: String, password: String, callback: AuthCallback){

firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d("AuthService", "Created new user! $email")
            callback.onUserCreationResult(AuthData("success", task.result?.user, null))

            task.result?.user?.let {
                DatabaseService.getDbInstance().collection("users")
                    .document(it.uid).set(it).addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Void> ->
                        Log.d("AuthService", "Added new user to database.")
                    }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(
                "AuthService",
                "Failed to create new user! $email ${task.exception?.message}"
            )
            callback.onUserCreationResult(AuthData("failure", null, task.exception?.message))
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in viewmodel:

```
fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {

    authService.createNewUser(email, password, object: AuthCallback {
        override fun onUserCreationResult(authData: AuthData) {
            if (data?.status.equals("success")) {
                authState.value = AuthState.AUTHENTICATED
            } else {
                authState.value = AuthState.INVALID_AUTH
                Log.d("AuthVM", result?.msg)
                authErrorMsg.value = result?.msg
            }

            currentUser.value = authData.data
        }

    })

}
```

I hope everything will work fine.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! From what I understand when the callback inside `AuthService` will set the value of mutable livedata e.g `authenticatedUserLiveData.value = AuthData(...)` it should be modified inside the viewmodel and the fragment since it is observing the viewmodel, right?

Comment: Also, passing around callbacks like this basically fails the purpose of ViewModel and LiveData.

Comment: Reply of first comment:
Yes, any kind of data manipulation will be happen in viewmodel. Because `View` only should know how to show data in UI, and `Model` should know where data exists and how it will be fetched. `Viewmodel` contains core business logic and it knows what data will be passed to `view`

Replay of second comment:
I don't think passing an object of an interface breaks the purpose of viewmodel. Because it's just pass an object as argument to repository. There must be a communicator. It can be live data, or Observable or interface.